# Stuck in Bootcamp. Unable to go back to MacOS

Tags: macos, mac, multi-boot, macbook-pro, boot-camp

So I have an MBP15,2015. Its startup disk was accidentally set to windows. There are 3 major problems that will basically get me fired:

My ctrl key on the internal mac keyboard is stuck (logic board issue I guess, been there for a while). I disabled the problematic keys using sharp keys on windows & Karabiner on MacOS

Boot camp. exe /assistant does not show up in the notification tray area. Even running it as admin literally does nothing

Combine 1 and 2, I have no way of going back to the Mac partition because I cannot hold the option key, I cannot boot into recovery, I cannot do anything.

My only hope is the command prompt. I'm dead because I have around all my project in Mac and a meeting in 3 hours.

Comment: Is there no on-screen keyboard that you can use?

Comment: On-screen keyboard is after the booting up. I want to boot to another drive all together.

Answer (score 0):

Hold Cmd/R at boot which will take you to Recovery.
From there you can access the Startup Disk control panel.

Your alternative would be an external keyboard.
If your macOS boot drive is APFS, windows cannot see it, so you have to do this at boot.

Comment: ya, my cmd/r isn't working because the ctrl is also pressed along with it on my MacBook's internal keyboard. It's the same with an external keyboard as well. I've tried reFIt and reFind, no progress. I've got half an hour left. Looks like I can't afford repairs after losing the job, lol. Nothing much I can do.

Comment: Then it sounds like an issue you should have got fixed before it became critical. 2 keys pressing as one is either a water-spill or a swollen battery; you need to get a professional to look at it… or, long-shot, get the case open, see if it relieves pressure.